# AWS Load Balancer with ACM and VM with Apache sometimes showing Request timed out ,How to resolve?

Tags: amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elb, aws-acm

We have AWS ec2 with ubuntu Apache with ACM and AWS elastic load balancer,
Sometimes it's returning "Error: Request timed out" ,sometimes works smoothly ,not able to identify
real cause.

HTTP and HTTPS already allowed in security group ,
listener are added in load balancer for 80 and 443.
also 80 request redirected to 443 port.
CNAME added for ACM in route 53
health check is fine.